# XCODE subview size not match

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

Please take a look at this picture:

[image]

I am trying to practice a multiview example from a book.

left is the main view , middle one is the subview connected to "Page 2" bar button.
the rightmost is the result from simulator.

The program is compiled successfully. However , the result is that the subview seems shift a little bit downward . I dont know whether it is the setting problem or code problem.

Comment: Seems like youve connected a window not a view to the page 2 button

Comment: thanks ur comment,may be i got confuse on window and view.

Comment: I added this code to those methods used to insert subview firstViewController.view.center = CGPointMake(160, 230); then every subview display in same position

Comment: you should not have to do that . Thats just a hack . You 're moving the whole thing so all views will get moved . Hmmm ...

Comment: May be I will get trouble in future development,but this example I just copy from the book but cannot get the same result with the book  :( .

Comment: Im also just a beginner ... If you do figure it out do post here so I can know .

Answer (score 0):

It may helpful

```
self.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

Comment: seems it not work for me , but I search autoresizingMask then i got other property.After I tested , it works for me .Thanks for ur help :) .
I added this, those subview position match!
firstViewController.view.center = CGPointMake(160, 230);